# File Upload with Image Preview and Delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file-upload

Is anyone able to help me customize the following code so that the file upload supports multiple file uploads, with a delete button for each image? At the moment, the code only supports one single image upload with preview/delete button. I tried changing the line  to  (which enabled multiple uploads) but this still only showed one image in the preview, along with one delete button.

The file upload code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Image preview</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var blank="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif";
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img_prev')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
      var img = input.value;
        $('#img_prev').attr('src',img).height(200);
    }
    $("#x").show().css("margin-right","10px");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").click(function() {
    $("#img_prev").attr("src",blank);
    $("#x").hide();  
  });
});
</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
#x { display:none; position:relative; z-index:200; float:right}
#previewPane { display: inline-block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);"/><br/>
<span id="previewPane">
<img id="img_prev" src="" alt="" />
<span id="x">[X]</span>
</span>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not hard to find plugins that do this

Comment: It's a customization of the Formidable Pro form plugin so that's not an option

Comment: Not sure why...swapping plugins is not complicated

Comment: I'll give it a go and post my solution if successful

Comment: I was unable to find a plugin that had both multiple upload previews and delete buttons- do you have any ideas where I could find one?Thanks

Comment: Instead of saying plugins aren't hard to find, how about you be more constructive and give examples of appropriate plugins?